# How to create a clustered index in SQL Server while still preserving the primary key?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a table named `Players` with these columns

```
Id, Name, Age
```

`Id` and `Age` are ints, and `Name` is a `char(50)`.

I want to create a clustered index on this table, so that the table will be sorted in ascending order by the `Name`. I have found out that every table with a primary key already has a clustered index on the primary key, and that there can only be one clustered index on a table, and if I want to add another one, I have to drop the primary key constraint that's on the `Id`.

My `Player.Id` is already as a foreign key in multiple other tables, so I still want to have the primary key constraint on the `Id`, but I also want a clustered index to sort the records by the name.

How can I do that in SQL Server? I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Why do you want an index by `Name`, are you looking up by that column? What queries are you trying to support? Why does it need to be clustered in your opinion, why can it not be a non-clustered index? That is not to say that this is all a bad idea, it might be a good one, but I don't know your use case. Long and short: you have to drop and recreate the primary key to change it to non-clustered, so that you can cluster on a different key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. First remove all FK constraints to your table `Player`
2. Then drop the primary clustered index on `Id`
3. Create a new primary key with a **non-clustered** index on `Player.Id` - use this command:
   `ALTER TABLE dbo.Player ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Player PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id);`
4. Then create a clustered index on `Player.Name`
5. Re-establish all FK constraints from all your table, to `Player`

Comment: How do I do 3? In SSMS I right click on the column in the Design tab of the table and I select "Select Primary Key", which creates a clustered PK. How do I create a pk with a non-clustered index?

Comment: It gives me an error at the NONCLUSTERED keyword saying "Incorrect syntax near 'NONCLUSTERED' "

Comment: I solved it by putting the NONCLUSTERED keyword before (Id)

Comment: Exactly - sorry, my typo

Comment: When I'm adding a foreign key after I added the index it sais: Table 'Players' has changed:
- Index 'Clustered_Index_On_Player_Name' was added and will be deleted.

Comment: What foreign key ? What is "it" that says table has changed ??

Comment: Now I am re-estabilshing the foreign keys I removed at 1. And when I m trying to save the changes to the table I re-established the FK, i get "Changes were made to the database while you were working. Do you want to update the database and override those changes to match yours?", then under I get the message I put in the last comment. "It" being a window that pops up when I m trying to save the changes after making the FK relationship.

Comment: I'd **strongly recommend** to dump the visual designer and use T-SQL statements to do this. It seems the designer detects that you created the nonclustered PK and then reverts that change.... forget the designer - use proper T-SQL

Comment: If you don't want to ditch the designer - then **at least** close the designer *before* you run that T-SQL statement to create the nonclustered PK, and then re-open the designer afterwards - don't leave it open while you run code-based DDL statements.....

Comment: T-SQL solved it, thank you!

Comment: I really suggest you get used to writing T-SQL for as much as you can; especially objects. The designer lacks functionality, and has "features" (read flaws). You're far better off learning the syntax to do the changes yourself in T-SQL; you'll find in the end that it's actually much faster and you can be much more specific with your design. For example; you'll be about to easily name your `CONSTRAINT`s (which you should really be doing already).